# Error 401 on API request on Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, oauth

I just want to connect to the [Sellsy API](https://api.sellsy.com/documentation/intro). So, I write a Ruby script:

```
require 'oauth'
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("user_key","user_pwd", :site => "https://apifeed.sellsy.com/0/request_token")
puts @consumer
@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token
session[:request_token] = @request_token
```

And I get a 401 error on:

```
#<OAuth::Consumer:0x008dfe229f3c10>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oauth0.5.3/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:236:in `token_request': 401 Unauthorized (OAuth::Unauthorized)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oauth-0.5.3/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:155:in `get_request_token'
from test0.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I just want to insure than there is no error on my script, I only want to connect to the API (no other request yet).

Thanks.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://github.com/faustus7/sellsy)? there's no documentation though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, script is here : https://github.com/bastienrobert/Sellsy-API

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: For anyone who uses this, oauth_signature = URI::escape(self.configuration.consumer_secret) + "&" + URI::escape(self.configuration.user_secret)